# Why moving a shared_ptr is allowed in a const_iterator?

Tags: c++11, iterator, constants, shared-ptr, move

Moving a shared_ptr will set the moved shared_ptr to nullptr so why it is allowed to do this in a const_iterator ?

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> sharedPtrVector;

sharedPtrVector.push_back(std::shared_ptr<std::string>(new std::string("test")));

for (std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>>::const_iterator it = sharedPtrVector.begin(); it != sharedPtrVector.end(); ++it) {
    // Not allowed if const_iterator
    //*it = nullptr;

    // Not allowed if const_iterator
    //*static_cast<std::shared_ptr<std::string> *>(&*it) = nullptr;

    // Allowed even if const_iterator
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> test(std::move(*it));
}
```

sharedPtrVector is in an undefined state after that.

Comment: `std::move` does not move, nor does it enforce moving. It rather allows moving from an lvalue. Whether or not an actual move operation occurs depends on the cv-qualification (type) of the operand, the the constructors of the destination type. In this case, I think the construction of `test` copies the `shared_ptr`.

Comment: I think in this case `std::move` returns `const std::shared_ptr<> &&`. There is no such constructor of `std::shared_ptr`, so closest match is `shared_ptr( const shared_ptr& r );` - usual copy constructor.

Comment: Thank you dip and zch, I am not able to reproduce the test when sharedPtrVector was in undefined state so maybe it was a bug elsewhere in my code. It's the copy constructor which is called like you said.

Comment: I suggest `for(auto it=sharedPtrVector.cbegin(); it!=sharedPtrVector.cend(); ++it)`

Comment: @ChrisDrew If you want to modernize this code, why not `for(auto const& e : sharedPtrVector)`?

Comment: @dyp, because the question was about const_iterator,  otherwise,  Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, `std::move` doesn't actually perform the move, it simply casts the iterator to an rvalue-reference so it is ready to be moved from. In the case of `const std::shared_ptr<T>&` it will cast to a `const std::shared_Ptr<T>&&` which is not accepted by the `std::shared_ptr<T>` move constructor so it will use the copy constructor instead.

This can be confirmed by checking if the `shared_ptr<T>` pointed to by the `const_iterator` is empty afterwards:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> sharedPtrVector;

sharedPtrVector.emplace_back(std::make_shared<std::string>("test"));

for (auto it = sharedPtrVector.cbegin(); it != sharedPtrVector.cend(); ++it) {
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> test(std::move(*it));
    if (*it)
        std::cout << "*it is not empty\n";
}
```